# RSpec Testing Rails Dates formatted with MomentJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, momentjs

We've have a curious (timezone?) problem around the testing of Date/Time in a Rails application.

The date being tested is `created_at` on a Rails object.

On the front end (`.html.slim` page with some AngularJS)

```
span.date
  | {{ comment.createdAt }}
```

Renders:

```
2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

but...

```
span.date
  | {{ comment.createdAt | moment: 'MMMM Do, YYYY' }}
```

Renders:

```
January 2nd, 2017
```

We are expecting `January 3rd, 2017`

I've tried `moment.utc: 'MMMM Do, YYYY'` but yields nothing.

Thoughts?

**EDIT** Background to how date is set on Comment object in spec.

1. A date object is created with `Date.parse`
2. Timecop freezes time
3. Comment object is created
4. `Comment.created_at` is rendered on a page but it is adjusted for the local time (this is expected behavior)

Perhaps with Timecop frozen there's a better way to set `current_date` so that when **momentJS** `thaws` it out it's in the same timezone that machine where tests are being run is?!?

```
let!(:current_date) { Date.parse('2017-01-03') }
...
background do
  Timecop.freeze(current_date)
end
...
context 'for story' do
  background do
    open_story_comments_modal

    within '.story-comments-container' do
      add_comment 'First comment message'
    end
  end
...
```

and in a shared helper we have

```
  def add_comment(text)
    fill_in 'comment[body]', with: text
    find('input[name="comment[body]"]').send_keys(:enter)

    expect(page).to have_css '.comments .comment-body', text: text
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z` is an ISO 8601 date string. The `Z` at the end indicates that it's in UTC timezone. Depending on locale timezone that date may be on January 3rd or January 2nd.

Storing a date with time and timezone is often a good idea but not in some edge cases. If you want to store a day, you shouldn't store a time and must not store a timezone. A date string without timezone is considered to be in locale time:

> If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time.
>
> ECMAScript 2015 (6th edition): [20.3.1.16 Date Time String Format](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)

Please note that this has changed since ECMAScript 2015 (6th edition). Until before it was specified as the opposite:

> The value of an absent time zone offset is "Z".
>
> ECMAScript 5.1 Edition / June 2011: [15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

As far as I know all browser followed that change some time ago.

Comment: Good points, and I agree. I think that for the person who wrote these specs the timezone wasn't an issue. I added an **EDIT** section above that might provide more insight.

Comment: Setting the timezone `Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'` and then current_date: `let!(:current_date) { Time.parse('2017-01-03').in_time_zone }` seems to have fixed things…don't know what else it'll break.

Comment: To resolve your issue you should not include timezone in ISO 8601 string if your value is representing a day. Even better would be to avoid including time at all.

Comment: agree. problem with this test is that it is ultimately testing a date that is derived from Rails `created_at` which is a `DateTime` (`Time`?). And not a `Date` so whoever wrote the spec initially set the `Date` but was ultimately testing a `DateTime`.  All in for a better solution but this is passing now so I'm moving along…